# Recompile Nginx with nginx-push-stream-module?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I've installed Nginx on Ubuntu with apt-get. Now i need to somehow add the module:

Their install suggests to recompile Nginx with the module: 
https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module/blob/master/README.textile

How can i do that when i have installed Nginx with apt-get?

I want to keep all my current settings and just get the module in there some how

Answer (score 1):

You basically can't .. You have to rebuild nginx, or find some ppa that has nginx compiled with those options